# Converting DataTable to XML using XElement as template

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an `XElement` (table template) with next code:

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="920" align="center">
 <tr>
     <td valign="top" width="200">
     </td>
     <td valign="top" width="400">
     </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Also I have `DataTable` which contains 2 columns and, for example 5 rows. Need to put my data from this `DataTable` to new `XElement`, using table template. I think that my function should looks like this:

```
public XElement Filling(XElement htmlTable, DataTable dataTable)
```

But I don't know how to get part of code from `htmlTable`:
For instance, how can I get only the first `td` with attribute `width="200"`.

Any suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the question entirely, but this is an example of how to get only the first `td` with attribute `width="200"` assuming that htmlTable contains the html shown in question :

```
var firstTd = htmlTable.Descendants("td").FirstOrDefault(o => o.Attribute("width").Value == "200");
```

- `htmlTable.Descendants("element_name")` will get any html element inside table tag (`tr` and `td` in this case).

Comment: You've opened my eyes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
private DataTable ParseHtmlTable( string html )
{
DataTable retVal = new DataTable();
XElement data = XElement.Parse( html );

// Gets rows of values.
List<string[]> records = ( from row in data.Descendants( "TR" ) select ( from cell in row.Descendants( "TD" ) select cell.Value ).ToArray() ).ToList();

// Ensure maximum columns
retVal.Columns.AddRange( new DataColumn[ records.Max( x => x.Length ) ] );

// Add records
records.ForEach( x => retVal.Rows.Add( x ) );

return retVal;
}
```